# Introduction to p-adic vector spaces

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, number-theory, reference-request, p-adic-number-theory

I'm interested in learning about vector spaces over $\mathbb{C}_p$ and $\mathbb{Q}_p$.

Most textbooks on p-adic numbers (Koblitz, Schikhof) focus on analysis and number theory.

**Is there any reference that covers at least the basics from the point of view of linear algebra?**

Comment: Finite-dimensional linear algebra largely works over all fields. What type of specifically $p$-adic issues did you have in mind? Look for books on $p$-adic functional analysis, perhaps.